# NPM Install with Git Clone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs project on GitHub. I use `git clone ${GitHubUrl}` to clone it for development. I use `npm install ${GitHubUrl}` or `npm update` for production use.

`git clone` sets up a git repo for development/committing, however it does not install package dependencies.

`npm install` installs package dependencies, however it does not set up a git repo for developing or committing.

Is there a command that combines these two? Surely this is a fairly common workflow and someone has a better solution for this. Perhaps something like `git clone ${GitHubUrl}` then some npm command?

A workable solution here could be commit `./node_modules` into the git repo, but that has obvious disadvantages.

Comment: `git clone foo && cd foo && npm i`?

Comment: I hate to be the guy asking why you want this but... You're right, adding node_modules is typically a bad idea. You should however use npm shrinkwrap to lock in tested versions for deployment. This doesn't solve your "problem" however.

Comment: @ivo I need to set up new development environments occasionally. Sometimes there is a dependency change. In both cases, `git clone` or `npm install/update` doesn't create a working development environment.

Right now, my workflow is to `git clone` my repo, then manually look through the `package.json` to install the dependencies.

@SLaks has the answer. I didn't realize `npm install` with no additional arguments installs the local `./package.json` file. The "correct" workflow for this type of work hasn't been as obvious as I hoped.

Comment: Oh sorry. When you mentioned running `npm install` in your question, I assumed you knew it was installing the local dependencies. Doing a fresh git clone + npm install like this will let you verify that all your dependencies are saved correctly in the package.json file.

Answer (score 20):

@SLaks has the right answer.

`git clone foo && cd foo && npm i`

I did not realize `npm install` with no additional arguments installs the local `package.json` file.